# Sort varchar as int when varchar is like "10.90 EUR"

Tags: mysql, sorting, int, varchar

I have a table with a field `diplayPrice` which is `varchar`. The field is filled with `10.90 EUR`, `3.90 EUR`, `119.00 EUR` and so on.

How can I sort this?

I tried several things, for example:

```
Select * From produkte ORDER BY length('DisplayPrice') 

Select * From produkte ORDER BY CAST(`DisplayPrice` AS SIGNED)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have price and currency in separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM produkte ORDER BY DisplayPrice * 1
```

It will help to convert DisplayPrice to number values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **substring** to obtain part that has only numbers and sort on it. **This is untested.**

```
select *,substring_index(displayPrice,' ',1) as displayPriceVal ...... order by displayPriceVal
```

Answer (score 0):

or just convert it into decimal so you can easily order it.

```
SELECT *  
FROM produkte  
ORDER by Cast(LEFT(DisplayPrice,LENGTH(DisplayPrice)-4) as dec(10,2))
```

But you need to cut your currency here. I advice you to locate this in another column to be more flexible(ie. sorting ;) )